# How to read and assert response from CSV using postman

Tags: automation, automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing

I have CSV file

```
GCNumber,facilityid,Balance
eqx93019107722,871,150
WEB270412011610,871,100
WEB270412014333,871,200
```

Request URL: `http://localhost/purchase/gift-card/{{GCNumber}}/for-facility/{{facilityid}}`

Wanted to write a test script using postman so that it will read data from CSV and verify amount from the response to the balance in csv file.

Response:

```
{
    "messages": null,
    "amount": 150.00,
    "currency": "USD"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Verify Amount - Passed"]= jsonData.amount === data.Balance;
```

Note:
In jsonData.amount - "amount" is the keyword from response
In data.Balance - "Balance" is the keyword from Heading of the CSV Sheet